# I wanted to fetch data from database while sending an email instead of hardcoded email in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I wanted to  fetch data from database while sending an email instead of hardcoded email in codeigniter

```
function send_user_email_missing_doc_test($to, $subject, $body, $attachment = null,$cc = NULL, $bcc = NULL,$bcc2 = NULL)
{
$this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->clear(TRUE);
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('Greetings@investorsloanservicing.com', 'Sharestates');
    //$this->email->reply_to('Kevin@investorsloanservicing.com','');
    $this->email->reply_to('Allen@investorsloanservicing.com');
    if ($cc != '') {
    $this->email->cc('help@ssapp.support');
    }
    if ($bcc != '') {
   // $ary=array('prinuannie@gmail.com,hemaravi7878@gmail.com');
    $ary=array('help@ssapp.support,Allen@investorsloanservicing.com');
    $this->email->bcc($ary);
    }
    if ($bcc2 != '') {
    //$ary=array('prinuannie@gmail.com,hemaravi7878@gmail.com');
    $ary=array('help@ssapp.support');
    $this->email->bcc($ary);
    }
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($body);
    if (isset($attachment) && !empty($attachment)) {
        foreach ($attachment as $path) {
            $this->email->attach($path);
        }
    }
    $this->email->send();
}
```

*the above code is my model page.I wanted to fetch email from the database instead of hardcoded **Greetings@investorsonlineservicing.com***
how to fetch data from database and get it in my model page and controller page,and i have manually only inserted the email id in database.i just want the data to be fetched instead of that Greetings@investorsloanservicing.com
Any help will be appreciated.

*database name is loanservice_sharestates and table name is common_email_settings which have id,title ,name,value ----values are given below----------- 1 , Greeting Mail , greeting_email , Greetings@investorsloanservicing.com *

Comment: ok, select what from what table with what condition? `select * from emails where id=12`?

Comment: database name is loanservice_sharestates and table name is common_email_settings which have id,title ,name,value                  ----values are given below-----------                                                                                                         1    ,    
Greeting Mail    ,
greeting_email    ,
Greetings@investorsloanservicing.com